# Angular4 adds second tbody element

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I want to represent some data in several tables. But Angular 4 adds many new divs to it and also a new tbody that destroys my table.

Her the template:

```
<div *ngFor= "let table of qmc.simplificationTable; let myIndex = index">

    <table class="table table-bordered col-md-4">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Group</th>
          <th>Vars</th>
          <th>Benutzt</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <div *ngFor= "let group of table let groupIndex = index">
          <div *ngFor= "let primeImplicant of group">
            <tr>
              <td>
                {{groupIndex}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{primeImplicant.toString()}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{primeImplicant._usedForCombination}}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </div>
        </div>
      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
```

this is the html result:
https://pastebin.com/z5UneyMf

You can see that angular4 adds a new tbody element to every

```
<tr>
```

These tbodies and the new divs destroies my table.

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you add a plunker for the same

Comment: Have you tried using `<ng-container *ngFor` instead of `<div *ngFor`?

Comment: That works just fine! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

`<div *ngFor`

with

```
<ng-container *ngFor
```

Thanks  yurzui (idea by yurzui in the comments)